# Identify the Game: reach the other side of the board, while avoiding barriers

Tags: identify-this-game

I was at a friend of a friend's house last weekend and played a cool game.  Here is what I remember:

- The game is played on a square board
- 2 or 4 players
- The goal of the game is to reach the opposite side of the board from which you start (before your opponent(s))
- On your turn you may

  - a) Move you piece forwards/backwards/left/right (not diagonal)
  - b) Place a barrier which you and your opponent cannot cross.  A barrier is a length two piece that goes between squares.

Anyone know the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are describing [Quoridor](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/624/quoridor).

> This abstract strategy is surprisingly deep for its simple rules. The
>   object of the game is to advance your pawn to the opposite edge of the
>   board. On your turn you may either move your pawn or place a wall. You
>   may hinder your opponent with wall placement, but not completely block
>   him off. Meanwhile, he is trying to do the same to you. First pawn to
>   reach the opposite side wins.

There is a similar game called [Blockade](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2559/blockade), but unlike Quoridor, the board for that one isn't square.