# What is the name of this game involving racing to the other side of the board and putting down barriers?

Tags: identify-this-game

Does anyone recognize this game, where players take turns in a square board, each turn a player can move his pawn or place a wall and the objective is to reach the other side of the board before the other player.

Here is a picture of a near end game.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identify the Game: reach the other side of the board, while avoiding barriers](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5960/identify-the-game-reach-the-other-side-of-the-board-while-avoiding-barriers)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not sure about the board, which looks like a homemade knockoff to me, but the game itself and its mechanics appear to be [Quoridor](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/624/quoridor).

[image: Quoridor box-art image]
<sup>— Image taken from http://boardgamegeek.com/image/110043/quoridor —</sup>

Comment: Man I love this game :)